# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError in Flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I am a new programmer and I just started making websites with flask, during my most recent project I had this problem with the database(Name of error is the title ;) ) This is my code ( I am making a mini youtube)

```
@app.route("/create_acc", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def create_acc():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form["nm"]

        check = ChannelDB.query.filter_by(name=name).first()

    if not check:
        email = request.form["em"]
        psw = request.form["ps"]

        channel = ChannelDB(name, email, psw, 0, 0)
        db.session.add(channel)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for("user"))
    else:
        abort(409, message="Video alredy exists")
```

This is where the error is accruing.

```
class ChannelDB(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
subs = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
num_of_videos = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

This is my database.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Login Page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="/create_acc", method="post">
        <p>Name: </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="nm"></p>
        <p>Email: </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="em"></p>
        <p>Password: </p>
        <p><input type="text" name="ps"></p>
        <p>Press this button when you fill the spots above</p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
    </form>
{% end block %}
```

This is my login . html file

Answer (score 1):

A full extract of the error would have been more conclusive. Nevertheless please try if you are able to add a record in the table using the terminal.

```
from app import *
channel = ChannelDB("Sample name", "sample email", "pass", 0, 0)
db.session.add(channel)
db.commit()
```

If the above command does not execute, drop the tables and recreate them.

```
from app import db
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
```

If not, try recreating the tables

Answer (score 0):

You may need to migrate your tables into the database. If you follow the `flask_sqlalchemy` [quickstart](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/), you can add your db schema with the command line operation `python manage.py db migrate`.

Comment: You make your self very clear but the problem is I don't know this python manage.py db migrate command can you pls give an example of the code and the command

Comment: Check out the link posted above ("quickstart") for reference. @Negative